# p-values of mu parameter in gamlss

Tags: r

I'm trying to fit inflated beta regression model to proportional data. I'm using the package `gamlss` and specifing the family BEINF. I'm wondering how I can extract the p-values of the `$mu.coefficients`. When I typed the command `fit.3$mu.coefficients` (as shown at the bottom of the my r code), it gave me only the estimates of Mu coefficients. The following is an example of my data.

```
mydata = data.frame(y = c(0.014931087, 0.003880983, 0.006048048,  0.014931087,
+           0.016469269, 0.013111447, 0.012715517, 0.007981377), index = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4))

mydata
        y      index
1 0.004517611     1
2 0.004351405     1
3 0.007952064     2
4 0.004517611     2
5 0.003434018     3
6 0.003602046     4
7 0.002370690     4
8 0.002993016     4

> library(gamlss)
> fit.3 = gamlss(y ~ factor(index), family = BEINF, data = mydata)
> summary(fit.3)

*******************************************************************
Family:  c("BEINF", "Beta Inflated") 

Call:  
gamlss(formula = y ~ factor(index), family = BEINF, data = mydata) 


Fitting method: RS() 

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Mu link function:  logit
Mu Coefficients:

                Estimate  Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)      -5.3994      0.1204  -44.858  1.477e-06
factor(index)2    0.2995      0.1591    1.883  1.329e-01
factor(index)3   -0.2288      0.1805   -1.267  2.739e-01
factor(index)4   -0.5017      0.1952   -2.570  6.197e-02

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Sigma link function:  logit
Sigma Coefficients:
             Estimate  Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -4.456      0.2514   -17.72  4.492e-07
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Nu link function:  log 
Nu Coefficients:
             Estimate  Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -21.54       10194  -0.002113    0.9984

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Tau link function:  log 
Tau Coefficients:
             Estimate  Std. Error    t value  Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)    -21.63       10666  -0.002028    0.9984

-------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of observations in the fit:  8 
Degrees of Freedom for the fit:  7
      Residual Deg. of Freedom:  1 
                      at cycle:  12 

Global Deviance:     -93.08548 
            AIC:     -79.08548 
            SBC:     -78.52938 
*******************************************************************

fit.3$mu.coefficients
   (Intercept) factor(index)2 factor(index)3 factor(index)4 
    -5.3994238      0.2994738     -0.2287571     -0.5016511
```

I really appreciate all your help.

Comment: The computations are in `gamlss:::summary.gamlss`,
but they are mixed with the code to display the results:
the easiest is probably to change that function 
so that it also returns what it computes.

Answer (score 1):

Use the save option in summary.gamlss, like this for your model above

```
fit.3 = gamlss(y ~ factor(index), family = BEINF, data = mydata)    
sfit.3<-summary(fit.3, save=TRUE)
sfit.3$mu.coef.table
sfit.3$sigma.coef.table
#to get a list of all the slots in the object
str(sfit.3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fit.3 = gamlss(y ~ factor(index), family = BEINF, data = mydata.ex)    
sfit.3<-summary(fit.3, save=TRUE) 
fit.3$mu.coefficients
sfit.3$coef.table # Here use Brackets []
estimate.pval<-data.frame(Intercept=sfit.3$coef.table[1,1],pvalue=sfit.3$coef.table[1,4],
                          "factor(index)^2"=sfit.3$coef.table[2,1] ,pvalue=sfit.3$coef.table[2,4],
                          "factor(index)^3"=sfit.3$coef.table[3,1] ,pvalue=sfit.3$coef.table[3,4],
                         "factor(index)^4"=sfit.3$coef.table[4,1] ,pvalue=sfit.3$coef.table[4,4])
```